# Is this kind of a bool method a bad practice?

Tags: c#, performance, boolean, xna

Sometimes I find myself writing a bool method that looks like this:

```
public bool isRunning()
    {
        if (!(move == Moving.None) && staminaRegan == true)
        {
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                EntityAnimation.interval = 10;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

(This is XNA by the way) As you can see, I have a bool isRunning in which I made an if statement where Im checking if (Player is moving) && (regains stamina, which is set to false once stamina reaches value lesser than 6.0f)
and then I simply check if Space is pressed, if yes then my Animation is faster(the smaller the interval, the faster is spritesheet changing), and then It sends true value, which means that Player is running, else Im not cause Space is not pressed.

And then I have to repeat this 'else' code outside of the first if statement  so it sends that Player is not running if Player is not moving or his stamina Regan is false;

So I was just wondering is this kind of a bool method considered a bad practice(where you retrun true and false value in nested if, and then return false outside nested if and repeat the same code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to have one return statement inside a method. Some argue about this, but it is an opinion.

it is also a good practice to make the if statement clear by removing unnecessary code:

```
public bool isRunning()
{
    bool result = false;
    if (move != Moving.None && staminaRegan)
    {
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            EntityAnimation.interval = 10;
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I agree having the one return statement and it being at the bottom, looks a lot cleaner. And seeing as you've already set the result to false initially, it doesn't need to be reset further down in the method - adding to the readability.

Comment: *It is a good practice to have one return statement inside a method.*  [No.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from) Force-fitting code into a specific pattern that doesn't match the actual logic being performed is what's bad.  See also http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored

Comment: Yes it is good practice to have only one return statement, it is even requiried in most companys I do jobs for. The code is much more readable but even more important better to maintain. I have seen people searching for hours why a newly added logmethod just before the retun statement at the bottom of a method does not get executed.

Answer (score 8):

The method has a *side effect*, that's why it's a *bad practice*:

```
 public bool isRunning()
```

When looking on method's signature we expect just `true`/`false` answer and nothing more. However, the method *changes* the instance's *state*:

```
  ...
  if (!(move == Moving.None) && staminaRegan == true)
    {
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            EntityAnimation.interval = 10; // <- Aaa! The interval is changed 
            return true;
        }
  ...
```

I suggest splitting the initial method into a property and a method

```
 // No side effect: just answer is running or not
 public bool IsRunning {
   get {
     return (move != Moving.None) && staminaRegan && KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);
   }
 }

 // Put the right interval based on instance internal state 
 // (if it's running etc.)
 public void AdjustInterval() {
   if (IsRunning) // and may be other conditions
     EntityAnimation.interval = 10; //TODO: move magic number into constant 
   else 
     EntityAnimation.interval = 65; //TODO: move magic number into constant
 }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I change some (other class- public static variable) value in the bool method, I just change some things before returning the true or false to bool :/

Comment: Because each method should do one thing only. You should make a method IsRunning and a method AdjustInterval. Than you can make another method CheckRunningAndAdjustInterval if you would like

Comment: (All this and ) No surprises!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code as follows; then the code isn't repeated:

```
public bool isRunning()
{
    if (move != Moving.None && staminaRegan && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        EntityAnimation.interval = 10;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want the redundant `else`:

```
public bool isRunning()
{
    if (move != Moving.None && staminaRegan && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
        EntityAnimation.interval = 10;
        return true;
    }

    EntityAnimation.interval = 65;
    return false;
}
```

I would consider introducing a named boolean to self-document somewhat, and I'd rename `staminaRegan` to `staminaIsRegenerating`

```
public bool isRunning()
{
    bool isMovingQuickly = (move != Moving.None) && staminaIsRegenerating && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);

    if (isMovingQuickly)
        EntityAnimation.interval = 10;
    else
        EntityAnimation.interval = 65;

    return isMovingQuickly;
}
```

Most importantly, though, you should rename the method to more accurately describe what it's doing:

```
public bool CheckIfRunningAndSetAnimationInterval()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we write code for people(other developers), of course machine execute a code but 80% of developer's work is reading the code.
Based on that I think flow of reading must be exactly same as flow of executing code - that's why I think multiply `return` statement not a bad thing, even better then only one return statement on the bottom of your method.

Comment: more than one return statement should be recognized by the compiler and it should give an error. This is so unreadable and the biggest supplier of bugs through the history of programming

Comment: @GuidoG: do you have any references to support your contention that multiple return statements are "the biggest supplier of bugs through the history of programming". I have regularly seen complex, convoluted code that introduces bugs when trying to implement a single return statement - where the code would have been much simplified & more maintainable to have multiple return statements.

Comment: If method will do only one things in the first place, then we will not have a problem with multiply return statements.

Comment: @PaulF Ever Just read every book about structured programming. Having more than one exit in a method was considered bad practice and in my opinion it still is. Yes structured programming is old but oop was inspired by it

Comment: @GuidoG: there are many arguments regarding whether SESE is good/bad practice & whether or not it is still applicable to many more modern languages - I was just interested in reading any information regarding it being "the biggest supplier of bugs through the history of programming".

Answer (score 0):

I like this style and i use it too. First, you can read the code more easily and second it has a debugging advantage as you can set breakpoints for the individual else cases. Otherwise you would need to use breakpoint conditions.